# Pause a shell script every x (mili)seconds to decrease immediate CPU usage

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I have a shell script which backups my MySQL database every hour. It's a basic script:

```
mysqldump --user=$USER --password=$PASS $DB > /$PATH/$DATE.sql &&
7z a -t7z -mx=9 /$PATH/$DATE.sql.7z /$PATH/$DATE.sql &&
rm /$PATH/$DATE.sql
```

I'm using a 7z compression, because:

- file permissions and owner/group aren't required to be kept
- the space saved by 7z compared to gzip is essential to me

What's troubling me is that the `7z` part (line 2) takes about 30 seconds and uses quite a lot of CPU during that time. There are 50% peaks on my server load graphs every hour from this and I'd like to get rid of those peaks.

I'm already executing this script with `nice`:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /path/to/backup.sh > /dev/null
```

The only solution I can come up with at this point is to somehow pause the execution of the `7z` part, let's say every second for 1 second. This could free up the CPU time for other processes.

Is this possible?

I'm doing something similar in my `.php` scripts, although the pauses are in loops, for example:

```
while($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
   usleep(250000);
   // process $d
}
```

I'd like the `7z` execution to sleep every X (something) for 1 second.

Comment: `Is this possible?` -- Highly unlikely.  You mention that you need high compression.  You'd need to pay for that (in terms of computing power).  Attempt to play a bit more with `nice`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
prlimit --cpu=10 7z a -t7z -mx=9 /$PATH/$DATE.sql.7z /$PATH/$DATE.sql
```

Which will limit the cpu usage to 10%

Comment: $ man prlimit
No manual entry for prlimit
$ prlimit
prlimit: command not found

Comment: @RichardRodriguez which os?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 13.10 Server, 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu

Comment: @RichardRodriguez : take a look [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man2/getrlimit.2.html)

Comment: On Ubuntu you can try `cpulimit` instead. Install with `apt-get install cpulimit`.

Answer (score 0):

How about configuring a limit for a user/group using the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file? And running the script/compression as specific user? After setting the limit you can test it using [fork bomb](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-bash-fork-bomb/).

Comment: This seems like a great idea. How would I run a cron job as a different user than root?